# Resolving a function used within a namespace-d template function

Tags: c++, templates, namespaces, name-lookup

I'm observing some seemingly strange behavior when trying to instantiate a template function.

In brief, I'm implementing a template function library.  For the purposes of this library, I am assuming that for each type T used to instantiate one of these templates, the user of this library will have implemented a function with a specific signature, say:

```cpp
void foo(const T& t)
```

I would like to define my library template functions within an enclosing namespace, say A.  Similarly, I would like these functions to be usable within another (user-defined) namespace, say B.  The overall usage pattern I have in mind is the following:

```
    #include <string>
    #include <iostream>

    // My library function
    namespace A {

    template <typename T>
    void my_library_function(const T& t) { foo(t); }

    }


    // Intended usage
    namespace B {

    // User writes a function foo(T) for the specific type T they want 
    // to use in conjunction with my_library_function()
    void foo(const std::string&  s) { std::cout << s << std::endl; }

    // User can then use my_library_function() in their own code
    void super_cool_user_function(const std::string& s) { A::my_library_function<std::string>(s); }
    }

    int main()
    {
        std::string s = "Hello world!";
        B::super_cool_user_function(s);
    }
```

I would expect this to work, since in this code `my_library_function()` is only used within the same namespace B where `foo(std::string& s)` is defined.  However, when trying to compile this, I get the following error:

```
> In instantiation of ‘void A::my_library_function(const T&) [with T =std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]’:
>
> example.cpp:8:43: error: ‘foo’ was not declared in this scope
>
> void my_library_function(const T& t) { foo(t); }
>
>example.cpp:8:43: note: suggested alternative:
>
>example.cpp:17:6: note:   ‘B::foo’
>
>void foo(const std::string&  s) { std::cout << s << std::endl; }
```

So, I have two (hopefully straightforward?) questions:

- Why is this error occurring?
- Is there a clean way of modifying my approach (the implementation of the template) to enable the intended usage shown above?

Thanks!

Comment: `B::foo` is not visible from inside `A` namespace, where you attempt to call it. Moreover, it's not even declared at the point where the template is defined. It can only be found via argument-dependent lookup at the point of instantiation, but the argument type, `std::string`, is not associated with `B` namespace either. It's unclear why you expect this to work.

Comment: Suppose that you have a `C` namespace, which has `foo` as well. If your code worked, how would `A::my_library_function` know, which `foo` to call? `B::foo` or `C::foo`? If you want to call `foo` unqualified in that template function, then you need to add some parameter to `foo`, whose type has a relation to `foo`'s namespace, so `foo` can be looked up by ADL.

Comment: Looking at your example in a vacuum, the only way you could get this to work is to `prototype` the `foo` function prior to its usage. The functionality you specifically want, is not possible.

Comment: Thanks for your quick replies everyone.

@geza: For ADL, would it suffice to introduce a typedef for std::string that is defined in the B namespace ( for example `typedef std::string MyString` ) and then replace `std::string` with `MyString` throughout?


@WBuck:  Could you elaborate what your prototyping suggestion would look like?  (Apologies if I'm being somewhat dense here ... )

Comment: @DavidRosen: no, it won't work. A typedef is not a new type, it's just an alias.